# iOS: changing the tint color of the back button?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

I have a navigation controller that pushes a UIViewController. I would like to change the tint color of the back button of the navigation item when a user presses on a certain button. Is this possible? I have tried using `[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:` but it only works on initialization (for example in viewDidLoad) and not otherwise.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this......

You need to use a **UIBarButtonItem** with a custom view. Something like this:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 70, 30)];
[button addTarget:target action:@selector(back:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_button_tap.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
UIBarButtonItem *buttonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

And put the button to the navigation bar, usually in a controller with UINavigationController:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = buttonItem;
```

Answer (score 7):

The easiest thing for me was to set the tint color for ALL uibarbutton items:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearance]setTintColor:[UIColor yourColor]];
```

And then explicitly setting the tintcolor for explicit navigationbuttons that I create & place on the navigationbar to other colors...

Saves me the headache of creating custom backbuttons when all I want to do is change the tint.

Comment: This only works for normal bar button. But not working for back button.

Answer (score 3):

In the method that is called on your button click, just put `[self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem setTintColor:[UIColor *whateverColorYouWant*]]`; I haven't tested it but I'm 99% sure that would work

**Edit:**
Just tested it, it works.

Comment: I just tried this and it crashed because backBarButtonItem was null.  Any idea why this would be and how to fix it?

Comment: Are you trying to change the color of a back button (it is the one shaped kind of like an arrow)? If it is just a regular barButtonItem, then you can try to change the tintColor of leftBarButtonItem and rightBarButtonItem.

Comment: I mean the arrow shape back button provided by the navigation controller, not a button that I've added in addition to that.

Comment: In what method are you trying to change the tint color? Have you referenced it anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a code that changes text and color of the back button:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [UIBarButtonItem new];
    [backButton setTitle:@"Back"];
    [backButton setTintColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];
}
```

Comment: Does this actually work? I remember that you need to use setLeftBarButtonItem with your customized button and set hidesBackbutton to TRUE but that you cannot override the backbar button item property (since it is generated when navigating)...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UINavigationBar class],[UIToolbar class], nil] setTintColor:[UIColor redColor]];
```